# Scala MongoDb client: from query string to builder

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

In the monogodb scala client ([reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4) and [api](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/scaladoc)), we need to build the queries using the [Builder](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/builders/) components. For example for a filter:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._

val q = and(gt("qty", 20), equal("user", "jdoe"))
collection.find(q)
```

The example above selects all documents where ther value of the qty field is greater than 20 and the value of the user field equals "jdoe".

I am wondering if there is a possibility to use the string rendered version directly without using the builders.

```
collection.find("{'qty' : { '$gt' : 20 }, 'user' : 'jdoe'}")
```

I am looking for that adaptation, to simplify the interaction with an external service that will provide the query in string format. And I also believe that it will be the simplest for a user to write the query in the same way he/she will do in the mongo shell.

Comment: Try `q.toBsonDocument.toJson`. For the other way around, `collection.find(BsonDocument.parse(aString))` should work (but be careful where you accept that string from).

Comment: Thanks as you mention `BsonDocument.apply(asString)` makes the reverse conversion. Note that is apply instead of parse. See [reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/bson/BsonDocument$.html))

Comment: ... which you can also write more idiomatic as `BsonDocument(aString)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments from [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo), the solutions is as follows:

```
val queryAsString = "{'qty' : { '$gt' : 20 }, 'user' : 'jdoe'}"
collection.find(BsonDocument(queryAsString))
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is really a solution, though. As a DBA, I'd much rather have the app developers prepare all the queries they need (so that we can think about indexes and such) as opposed to accepting strings from who knows where. So unless this is some ad-hoc reporting tool, I'd try to stick with the builders.

Comment: I considered it to be the solution to the problem mentioned if the question. Thanks for the comments. It's true that maybe is not a good option to provide the possibility to define as string. In my case I am providing a API, and there I wanted to use plan strings to being with.